# Training data for open nlp model - Outcome 1 and model not compatible with finder

Tags: opennlp

I'm currently facing a problem training a new ner model with the opennlp toolkit.
I found an example online on training a new model for drug names.
The sample data that's used for the training looks like this

```
<START:medicine> Augmentin-Duo <END> is a penicillin antibiotic that contains two medicines - <START:medicine> amoxicillin trihydrate <END> and <START:medicine> potassium clavulanate <END>.
```

I'm trying to train a model to recognize species names and managed to create a sample data set of roughly 35,000 sentences.
The every sentence contains atleast one species name that I tagged accordingly to the drug sample data.
It looks like this

```
A flatfish is a member of the order <START:sname> Pleuronectiformes </END> of ray-finned demersal fishes, also called the Heterosomata, sometimes classified as a suborder of Perciformes.
```

Now the interesting part. If I start the training I get this message

> Number of Outcomes: 1
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Model not compatible with name
> finder!

For "testing" purposes i copied one sentence of the drug example at the beginning of my list of sentences and suddenly I get "Number of Outcomes: 2".

Now I have no idea why my samples get recognized as only one Outcome.
Is every species name only allowed to occur once in my sample data? What else could be the problem? Do I have to tag at least 2 species names in one sentence?
Have no ideas left why my code works with the sample data for drugs but not my data, hope someone can help me out here.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you've tagged the dataset incorrectly.

you've done `<START:sname> Pleuronectiformes </END>` instead of `<START:sname> Pleuronectiformes <END>`

that `/` might be it, make sure you're giving all the spaces correctly and you have each sentence on a single line in the training data.

If this doesn't work, post nuggets of your training data.

Comment: Wow. I feel incredibly dumb right now. Thank you for saving my day - again! Can't believe i didn't see that.. thank you very much!